# How come a YouTube link isn't transformed into a shortcode inside the post content?

Tags: posts, shortcode

Assume I wanted to add the following video link `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YceOU89fzMM&feature=emb_title` inside a post, in a non-Gutenberg environment.

What happens is WordPress actually displays the `iframe`, so, there is some wrapping being done...somewhere, but I don't exactly know where that is.

What's going on here?

How does WP transform that link to an iframe and make it pretty? The reason for asking this is because there's absolutely no way to take that link from a search within the post and then grabbing its output. **To me, the developer, it's just a link whose output that an user sees I cannot reproduce.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On output WordPress parses the content and finds any links on their own line and for links from [supported sites](https://wordpress.org/support/article/embeds/#okay-so-what-sites-can-i-embed-from) it uses [oEmbed](https://oembed.com) to get the embed code for the linked media and replaces the link with it.

It does this with [`WP_Embed::autoembed()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_embed/autoembed/), which is added as a filter to `the_content`.

Comment: So, in order for me to get the right output, I should first of all `esc_html( the_content() )`, go through the raw body of the post, see if there's a link possibly with some function that already exists, see if WP supports it, then rebuild the embed based on the link?

Comment: What? Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Given a post, I want to look inside and see if there's an embed **as the very first thing inside that post.** If the user has done this and there's a specific option turned on, then it means, for that post format, he wants the said embed to be the featured item on the homepage. I want to be able to display it.

Comment: Then you should post that as a question. The question you posted here is “how does WordPress transform links into an iframe”.

Comment: I'm not sure how to even ask the question, I've been through 2 drafts and I think the question I wanna ask is a natural question to ask after this one. Can you help a bit? If you can ask the question yourself and self-answer it, I'll upvote for visibility.